# 403 – forbidden exception while using the Jsoup

Tags: java, url, jsoup, http-status-code-403

I need to fetch the HTTP status code of this website "https://in.bookmyshow.com/". So I tried using Jsoup to fetch the status of this particular website but the site denies the request hence ending up with 403 forbidden error. It would be great if someone can provide a solution to fetch the status code programatically.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "https://in.bookmyshow.com/";

    try {
        // Fetch the HTML content using Jsoup
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).execute();
        int statusCode = response.statusCode();
        System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + statusCode);

        // If you need to parse the HTML content further using Jsoup, you can do it like this:
        Document document = response.parse();
        // ... Add your parsing logic here ...

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note: Adding User Agent also doesn't work in this case

Comment: If all you need is a HTTP status code, you don't need something as advanced as JSoup. Just use `URL.openConnection()`.

Comment: Of course, there's no such thing as "http status code of the website". For each request, you can get a different status code. The request you are currently making gives you status code 403, which is a perfectly valid answer to the question.

Comment: URL.openConnection() also resulted in 403 forbidden status and that's the reason I tried with JSoup

Comment: Right, so you made the same request with a different library, and expected a different result. May I suggest changing the actual request instead?

Comment: Request URL:
https://in.bookmyshow.com/
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
200 (from service worker)
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce getting a 403 when making that request from Java, while getting 200 when making that request from a browser. So now it's your job to find out how those requests are different. If you know the owner of the site, they might be able to help you with that. If not, inspect the request in your browser and reproduce it as closely as possible.